Add a text below the related attribute option based WooCommerce variation custom field
In woocommerce website, I want to add a tag or toolkit or something that will show a text that its recommanded/most choosen/most sold item, I want to show it around a variant option that i chose from the backend.
i.e. I have three variations 1mm, 3mm and 5mm. So I want to show Most Choosen text around 3mm variation.

My Approch :
What I was trying to do what we can do is that for the variable products, we add a custom checkbox in the variant option, so I can select a variant. for this variant add a class="choosen-variant". for this class add an pseudo selector before or after and add this html element : Most Choosen Option
Code I tried :
I tried this code to add custom checkbox and add the class. It added a variant custom checkbox but its not adding the class.
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'add_most_chosen_variation_field', 10, 3);
function add_most_chosen_variation_field($loop, $variation_data, $variation)
{
    $most_chosen = get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_most_chosen_variation', true);
    ?>
    <label for="most-chosen-variation-<?php echo $loop; ?>">
        <input type="checkbox" name="most_chosen_variation[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" id="most-chosen-variation-<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="1" <?php checked($most_chosen, '1'); ?> />
        Most Chosen Variation
    </label>
    <?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_most_chosen_variation_field', 10, 2);
function save_most_chosen_variation_field($variation_id, $loop)
{
    if (isset($_POST['most_chosen_variation'][$loop])) {
        $most_chosen = $_POST['most_chosen_variation'][$loop] ? '1' : '0';
        update_post_meta($variation_id, '_most_chosen_variation', $most_chosen);
    }
}


add_action('wp_head', 'add_most_chosen_variation_css');
function add_most_chosen_variation_css()
{
    ?>
    <style>
        .most-chosen-label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: #f0ad4e;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 2px 5px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_most_chosen_variation_js');
function add_most_chosen_variation_js()
{
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('form.variations_form').on('show_variation', function(event, variation) {
                // Remove the "Most Chosen" label from all variation options
                $('.most-chosen-label').remove();

                // Add the "Most Chosen" label to the selected variation option
                var mostChosenOptionValue = variation.variation_id;
                var variationOption = $('.variations .value select option[value="' + mostChosenOptionValue + '"]');
                variationOption.after('<span class="most-chosen-label">Most Chosen Option</span>');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

HTML Code from the store :
<div class="cfvsw-swatches-container cfvsw-product-container" swatches-attr="attribute_kies-uw-capaciteit">

<div class="cfvsw-swatches-option cfvsw-label-option" data-slug="11.6 Ah €320,00" data-title="11.6 Ah €320,00" style="min-width:100px;min-height:50px;border-radius:10px;">

<div class="cfvsw-swatch-inner">11.6 Ah €320,00</div></div>

<div class="cfvsw-swatches-option cfvsw-label-option" data-slug="13.4 Ah €370,00" data-title="13.4 Ah €370,00" style="min-width:100px;min-height:50px;border-radius:10px;">

<div class="cfvsw-swatch-inner">13.4 Ah €370,00</div></div></div>

Script I found on a the reference Website that use the similar logic :
<script type="text/javascript">
       var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{"183":{"id":"183","code":"far_vermogen_na_revisie","label":"Capaciteit na revisie","options":[{"id":"596","label":"8,7 Ah (313 Wh)","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["1250"]},{"id":"799","label":"11 Ah (396 Wh)","price":"50","oldPrice":"50","products":["1251"]},{"id":"739","label":"13,6 Ah (490 Wh)","price":"95","oldPrice":"95","products":["1252"]}]}},"template":"\u20ac\u00a0#{price}","basePrice":"299","oldPrice":"299","productId":"1249","chooseText":"Kies een optie...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":true,"showIncludeTax":true,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":21,"currentTax":21,"inclTaxTitle":"Incl. BTW"}});
        // Values overnemen vanuit de select
        jQuery('.super-attribute-select').each(function() {
            var attributeId = jQuery(this).data('atributeid'),
                outputHtml = [];

            jQuery(this).find('option').each(function(index, element) {

                let $element = jQuery(element), value = $element.val();

                if (value !== '') {
                    let productId;

                    if (element.config && element.config['products'] && element.config['products'].length > 0) {
                        productId = element.config['products'][0];
                    }

                    let mostChosenOptions = [];
                    let isMostChosenOption = index === 2;

                    if (mostChosenOptions.length > 0) {
                        isMostChosenOption = mostChosenOptions.toString().includes(productId);
                    }

                    let optionClasses = ['option-item', 'col-xs-4'];

                    if (isMostChosenOption) {
                        optionClasses.push('option-item-most-chosen');
                    }

                    outputHtml.push('<div class="' + optionClasses.join(' ') + '" data-attribute="' + attributeId + '" data-value="' + value + '">');
                    outputHtml.push('<span>' + $element.html() + '</span>');

                    if (isMostChosenOption) {
                        outputHtml.push('<span class="most-chosen-label">Meest gekozen optie</span>');
                    }
                    outputHtml.push('</div>');
                }
            });

            jQuery('#product-option-values-' + attributeId).html(outputHtml.join(''));
        });

       jQuery('.product-option-values').on('click', '.option-item', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           setAttributeValueCustom(jQuery(this).data('attribute'), jQuery(this).data('value'));
       });

        function setAttributeValueCustom(attributeId, value) {
            jQuery('#product-option-values-' + attributeId + ' > .option-item').each(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).data('value') === value) {
                    jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
            });
            jQuery('#attribute' + attributeId).val(value);
            spConfig.reloadPrice();
        }

        jQuery('body').bind('form_submitted', function() {
            // Vorige fouten verwijderen
            jQuery('.validation-advice-copy').each(function() {
                jQuery(this).remove();
            });

            // Controleren of er fouten zijn... deze zijn namelijk verborgen
            jQuery('.super-attribute-select').each(function() {
                if(jQuery(this).hasClass('validation-failed')) {
                    attribute_id = jQuery(this).data('atributeid');
                    validationadvice = jQuery(this).next('.validation-advice').html();
                    jQuery('#product-option-values-'+attribute_id).after('<div class="validation-advice validation-advice-copy">'+validationadvice+'</div');
                }
            });
        });
       jQuery(function(){
           jQuery('.option-item').first().click();
       });
    </script>


It seems that you are using a 3rd party plugin to display variations as swatches, so you need to provide the generated HTML code in your question for those 3 variation attribute options...

Hi @LoicTheAztec, Thank you for your answer. I edited and added the HTML, hope its what you were refering. I also added the script from the website that use similar feature.

First, I have revised your code with a more recent code version for the admin product custom checkbox setting field:
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'add_most_chosen_variation_field', 10, 3);
function add_most_chosen_variation_field($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    printf('<label for="most-chosen-%s">
        <input type="checkbox" name="most_chosen[%s]" id="most-chosen-%s" %s /> %s</label>', 
        $loop, $loop, $loop, checked( get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_most_chosen', true), '1', false ),
        __("Most Chosen Variation", "woocommerce") );

}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'save_most_chosen_variation_field', 10, 2);
function save_most_chosen_variation_field($variation, $loop) {
    if (isset($_POST['most_chosen'][$loop])) {
        $variation->update_meta_data('_most_chosen', $_POST['most_chosen'][$loop] ? '1' : '0');
    }
}

Now, you need first to retrieve the attribute value displayed in your provided HTML code for the "most chosen" variation.
In the function below you need to set up the correct attribute taxonomy (always start with "pa_" + the attribute slug, like for example for "Color" attribute, the taxonomy is "pa_color").
function get_most_chosen_variation_attribute( $product ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_color'; // <== Define the correct attribute taxonomy

    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations('') as $variation ) {
        if ( $variation->get_meta('_most_chosen') ) {
            return $variation->get_attribute($taxonomy);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

Then now to display "Most Chosen Option" below the related option use the following (assuming that "11.6 Ah €320,00" is for example the real attribute value):
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'most_chosen_variation_display_js' );
function most_chosen_variation_display_js() {
    global $product;

    if ( $attribute_slug = get_most_chosen_variation_attribute( $product ) ) :

    $text = __('Most Chosen Option', 'woocommerce');

    wc_enqueue_js("$('.cfvsw-swatches-container .cfvsw-label-option').each( function(){
        if( $(this).data('title') === '{$attribute_slug}' ) {
            $(this).addClass('most-chosen').append('<span>{$text}</span>');
        }
    });");

    endif;
}

add_action('wp_head', 'most_chosen_variation_css');
function most_chosen_variation_css() {
    ?>
    <style>
    .most-chosen span {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 5px;
        background-color: #f0ad4e;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 2px 5px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}

If the related attribute value is instead a substring of "11.6 Ah €320,00", like "11.6", you should replace this line:
if( $(this).data('title') === '{$attribute_slug}' ) {

with:
if( $(this).data('title').includes('{$attribute_slug}') ) {

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Thank you @LoicTheAztec, Its is working. Starting with "pa_" was not working, I have to remove it.
I am having one issue, once I select variation 1 as a most choosen option, it works perfectly. But When I want to make the Variation 2 the most chosen option so I check variation 2 and uncheck variation 1, both the option will be checked. I wont be able to uncheck after checking.

Starting with "pa_" was not working if you are using custom local product attributes… In all cases, you can also use the product attribute name.
